# browser game map

Tags: browser, dictionary

I'm making a browser based game, and need to have a map page where a player can move around and go to different locations.

Currently it loads each tile in your view (about 8x8) from the database, each time you move. It's probably not a good way.

I want a map about 2000x2000 pixels, but in a small window of about 300x300. If it has to be one image then I guess that will have to do.

It doesn't need to scroll smoothly, just jump 16 or so pixels each move.

I've looked around and their are so many different variations. My site is php and jquery, is jquery the way to go? Or would html5 be better?

Looking for some pointers on this.